# how to get images from Assets.xcassets with wildcard in Swift (Xcode)?

Tags: swift, search, wildcard, assets

i tried to find some way, how to use wildcards to find all "leaf-*" images in Assets.xcassets and load them in an array as SKTexture. As far as i know it is also not possible to load only images from a folder in an asset catalog, am i right?

```
let leafTexturesArray = [SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "leaf-brown-1.png")!), SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "leaf-brown-2.png")!), SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "leaf-green-1.png")!), SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "leaf-green-2.png")!), SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "leaf-green-3.png")!)]
```

that works perfect - but it seem not to be the clean way to load 50 different leaf-textures?

is there anything like:

```
var finishedArrayWithAllLeafImages = [SKTextures]()
for image in Assets.xcassets {
   if "leaf*" is in images.filename {
      finishedArrayWithAllLeafImages.append(SKTexture(image: image.name))
   }
}
```

?

i tried to find other ways to get a wildcard working, like finding images from a folder in the project, but i don't see the point where i search after a wildcard?

it would be cool, if anyone has any hint or idea how to realize this idea!

big thanks,